# Looping in a data frame in R until a certain condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

We have the current data frame df as below

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Name = c("Chris", "J", "Kemp", "President,", "CEO & ", "Director", "Ashton", "K", "Christian", "Analyst"), 
                  Font = c("Font A", "Font A", "Font A", "Font B", "Font B", "Font B", "Font A", "Font A", "Font A", "Font B"))
```

The expected Output is

```
final_df <- data.frame(Name =  c("Chris J Kemp", "Ashton K Christian"), Designation = c("President, CEO & Director", "Analyst"))
```

So basically I want to add names until there's a certain font type in column Font and this is of course a sample of the huge data frame I'm dealing with. Thanks for the help in advance !

Sorry all your efforts earlier. This question has been re-edited a bit.

Comment: Does `"Font A"` and `"Font B"` repeat again for another person? Can you provide an example with atleast 2 people so that it is easier to provide a general answer.

Comment: Yes I have more names under the df$Name column but the sequence remains the same with a Name falling under Font A and Designation falling under Font B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:12), 
  Name = c("Chris", "J", "Kemp", "President,", "CEO & ", "Director", 
           "Bad", "D", "King", "Best,", "Teacher & ", "Friend"), 
  Font = c("Font A", "Font A", "Font A", "Font B", "Font B", "Font B",
           "Font A", "Font A", "Font A", "Font B", "Font B", "Font B")
)
```

You can do:

```
df$group <- cumsum(c(TRUE, df$Font[-1] != df$Font[-length(df$Font)]))
final_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(lapply(split(df$Name, df$group), paste, collapse = " "), ncol = 2))
colnames(final_df) <- c("Name", "Designation")
```

A grouping row of consecutif font is created. Then `split` allows to have a list per font then you can reformat data using `paste`.

Output:

```
                        Name             Designation
1               Chris J Kemp              Bad D King
2 President, CEO &  Director Best, Teacher &  Friend
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. But I have more names under the df$Name column with the sequence remaining the same with a Name falling under Font A and Designation falling under Font B 
As of now, the issue I'm facing is that I'm getting all the names and designations stacked under a single row.

Comment: Could you please update your example so that we could better understand your problem and adapt our answers?

Comment: @AishwaryaSharma please have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Font = recode(Font, 'Font A' = 'Name', 'Font B' = 'Designation'), 
         ID = data.table::rleid(Font)) %>%
  group_by(ID, Font) %>%
  summarise(Name = toString(Name), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(ID = ceiling(ID/2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Font, values_from = Name) %>%
  select(-ID)

#  Name                 Designation                 
#  <chr>                <chr>                       
#1 Chris, J, Kemp       President,, CEO & , Director
#2 Ashton, K, Christian Analyst
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this method:

```
df_final = as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lapply(unique(df$Font),function(i){paste(collapse = ' ', df[df$Font%in%i,"Name"])})), byrow=T,ncol = 2))

colnames(df_final)=c("names", "designation")
```

Let me know if it's ok

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. But I have more names under the df$Name column with the sequence remaining the same with a Name falling under Font A and Designation falling under Font B 
As of now, the issue I'm facing is that I'm getting all the names and designations stacked under a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Font, fontnum) %>%
  summarize(Tmp = paste(Name, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  mutate(ID = fontnum %/% 2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Font, values_from = Tmp) %>%
  transmute(Name = `Font A`, Designation = `Font B`)
```

where

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:12, 
  Name = c("Chris", "J", "Kemp", "President,", "CEO & ", "Director", 
           "Bad", "D", "King", "Best,", "Teacher & ", "Friend"), 
  Font = c("Font A", "Font A", "Font A", "Font B", "Font B", "Font B",
           "Font A", "Font A", "Font A", "Font B", "Font B", "Font B")
)
```

and

```
df$fontnum <- cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(as.numeric(factor(df$Font))))))
```

And the result will be

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Name         Designation               
  <chr>        <chr>                     
1 Chris J Kemp President, CEO &  Director
2 Bad D King   Best, Teacher &  Friend
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. But I have more names under the df$Name column with the sequence remaining the same with a Name falling under Font A and Designation falling under Font B As of now, the issue I'm facing is that I'm getting all the names and designations stacked under a single row. –

Comment: From this answer I learnt that quotation marks can be used in place of backticks when calling functions that need backticks - this would be useful considering that I do not have backticks on my keyboard (have to use shortcut), but at the same time I might prefer backticks in order to avoid confusion with the use of quotation marks for strings. Thanks in any case

Comment: If you are using `group_by(Font, ID = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(as.numeric(factor(Font)))))) %/% 2)` you don't need neither the `mutate` nor the definition of `fontnum` (outside the pipe).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative strategy with `dplyr`: Data used from Clemsang (many thanks!)

1. `group_by` and divide `ID` by 3
2. `summarise` and `collapse` (bring rows to one row by group)
3. use `group_split` to split the groups (returns a list)
4. use `bind_cols` to get a dataframe
5. tweak names and select

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Font, ceiling(ID/3)) %>%
    summarise(Name = paste0(Name, collapse = " ")) %>% 
    group_split(Font) %>%
    bind_cols() %>% 
    select(Name = Name...3, Designation=Name...6)
```

```
  Name         Designation               
  <chr>        <chr>                     
1 Chris J Kemp President, CEO &  Director
2 Bad D King   Best, Teacher &  Friend
```